# Anderson localization in the continuum case

Tags: wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, randomness, anderson-localization

I haven't looked into Anderson localization before. A quick review of the available information gives the impression that this phenomenon has mainly been studied for the case of a discrete random Schrödinger equation. Therefore, I have the following question: does localization of the wave function take place for the one-dimensional random continuum Schrödinger equation? In particular, in the case of a bounded potential $V(x)$, such that $0 \leq V(x) \leq V_0$, which can be obtained by randomly placing potential barriers of finite random width and height on the line. If the answer to this question is “yes,” then are localized states with energies $E>V_0$ possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, Anderson localization persists to a continuum model.
2. The statement is actually much stronger than this. For *any* value of $V_0$, *all* states will be localized in 1d (and, marginally, in 2d as well).

The first experimental observation of Anderson localization in matter waves, by the group of Nobel laureate Alain Aspect, was in an effective 1d continuum system: https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.1621 . The disorder potential was somewhat different than the one you are envisioning, but that paper and its references should have useful information. The one caveat of which I am aware is that all states will only be localized as long as the power spectrum of the disorder is unbounded. In other words, for the potential you suggested, there must be no minimum width of the boxes.